# Masonry not working properly with bootstrap nav-tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

I have created bootstrap tab & i apply masonry in the second tab. But not working perfectly masonry content.

Live link for check http://wpdevschool.com/masonry/

I have use html markup bellow

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="masonary_layout">
    <div id="masonary_content_area">
    <div class="single_masonry_content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js bellow

```
 <script>

$(function(){
var $container = $('#masonary_content_area');            
//$container.imagesLoaded(function(){                    
  $container.masonry({
     itemSelector: '.single_masonry_content',
  });
 //});
 });

 </script>
```

please help me.

Comment: I can't find any  `content` inside `div`

Comment: please check live link & click second icon tab

Comment: please check "masonary_content_area" height 40px; window resize then work fine

Comment: # Lalji Tadhani  not working

Answer (score 0):

please check attach image its working fine then window resize[image]

Comment: Yes it working all time when window resize.But I wouldn't to resize window.

Comment: check your function and call on click tab

Comment: change tab sequence & try

Comment: first load Masonry Tab

Comment: Yes work it. But have any solution for Masonry load in second tab?